# are the frames of the (mpeg) video are dependent or independent

Tags: video, encryption, parallel-processing, gpgpu

I am trying to obtain parallelism in the encryption of the video, means I am trying to make the process of the video encryption parallel. For doing anything parallel the data must be independent. So my question is whether the frames of the video are dependent or independent? i.e. is it possible to process individual frames seperately or in parallel?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt frames? Are you dealing with streaming data? Why do you care if the frames are independent? I think that's the wrong question you're asking.

Comment: No I am not dealing with streaming data. I am dealing with the stored data. If the frames are independent then I will be able to seperate the frames and encrypt them in parallel and stitch them back to get an encrypted video.

Comment: Why don't you then encrypt the video as data? I see no reason to work on frames. Simply work on bytes.

Comment: ok. But is it independent because the main requirement of the video encryption is that the data should be independent

Comment: Sure later bytes are dependent on previous bytes, but that doesn't mean that you can't encrypt it in parallel, because you're not dealing with streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but as it still pops up in searches...

AES encryption supports different modes, and the two most common are CTR and CBC.

From the point of view of this question, the important thing to note is that both methods encrypt the data block, by block - i.e. they split the data into equal size blocks, and encrypt each block one by one.

For CBC, the output of the last block encrypted is used as part of the 'seed' for the encryption algorithm for the next block, so the order of the blocks is very important. There are actually two common subsets of CBC, CSC-S and CBC-1. CBC-S essentially uses the same seed for each group of data being encrypted so it is possible to encrypt different groups of data in parallel.

For CTR, a simple counter is used as the seed, usually just incrementing by one as nobody has shown this to be less secure (to date...), so the order of the blocks is important but it is possible to manage parallel encryption by managing the counters appropriately.

So in summary, it is often possible to encrypt in parallel but it does require careful management of the parallel processes and an awareness of the encryption mode being used.

The ISO CENC spec (ISO/IEC 23001-7:2016(E) - good to check the latest verion) provides much more detail including some good diagrams of the different modes and an explanation of 'sub sample' encryption (essentially not encrypting all the video file, so metadata, file info etc is not encrypted, for example) which will likely be important for anyone looking at this also.